# listview changes order

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous, picasso

1. I load images via Picasso Library in my custom adapter and then show it in my ListFragment. When I am trying to scroll, some of the images changes order (I think it is something wrong with reusing cells).
2. What is the best place to download images asynchronously? I do it in my custom adapter with viewholder.

   ```
   public class PostsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private static final String TAG = "tag.example.tag";
   private static final String URL_PREFIX = "http://someapi.com/v1/api/";
   private Context mContext;
   private ArrayList<Post> mData;
   private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

   public PostsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> data) {
     mContext = context;
     mData = data;
     inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
     return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
     return mData.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int i) {
     return i;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int i) {
     return i;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
     View v = view;
     ViewHolder holder = null;
     if(view == null)
       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_listviewrow, null);

     holder = new ViewHolder();

     holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     Post post = (Post) mData.get(i);
     // Download image with Picasso
     holder.imageView.setTag(post.getPictureUrl());
     Picasso.with(mContext).load(URL_PREFIX + post.getPictureUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
     return v;
   }

     static class ViewHolder {
       TextView titleTextView;
       ImageView imageView;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
Changed getView method to something like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_listviewrow, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
        // Get position
        Post post = (Post) mData.get(i);

        holder.titleTextView.setText(post.getTitle());
        Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(mContext);
        picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        picasso.load(URL_PREFIX + post.getPictureUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {}
        });

    return view;
}
static class ViewHolder {

    TextView titleTextView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

}
```

Anyway, Do you think the adapter is the right place to put download tasks?

Comment: Usually when it comes to loading things from the internet I use an AsyncTask. It prevents blocking and seperates tasks the View shouldn't be concerned with. See [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @Remymoan Picasso is doing background job. I can make my own image downloader with AsyncTask as you mentioned above. But the question is where should i put my background tasks?

Comment: You can just put it in a seperate class file. I haven't worked with Picasa, but I assume that Picasa is already loading it in the background for you. If that is the case, you should be fine.